# how to set url to media player using java script or c#?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to set media player url as new url that is i get from Session["song"] how to set and can anyone tell what i wrong did in my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    string url = ((string)(Session["song"]));
    Label5.Text = url; // url value here displaying  correct, but how to set that to media player???
  }
```

**in aspx page i have media player code:**

```
<OBJECT Id="Player" CLASSID="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" CODEBASE="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab# Version=5,1,52,701" STANDBY="Loading Microsoft Windows® Media Player components..." TYPE="application/x-oleobject" width="280" height="46">
          <param name="URL" value="+url+" />
          <param name="enable" value="true" />
          <param name="animationatStart" value="true"/>
          <param name="transparentatStart" value="true"/>
          <param name="autoStart" value="true"/>
          <param name="showControls" value="true"/>    
          <param name="Volume" value="-300"/>
          <embed Id="Player" type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" src="+url+" width=280 height=46 autostart=1 showcontrols=1 volume=-300 />
        </OBJECT>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the second line your aspx media player embed code with the following line

```
<param name="URL" value='<%= Convert.ToString(Session["Song"]) %>' />
```

Comment: i has seen using above line got error unexpected character '\' and newline constant.

Comment: try this line and check `<param name="URL" value='<%= Convert.Tostring(Session["Song"]) %>' />`

Comment: If my answer helped select it is answer, if you figured something yourself then you can post the answer, it might help someone in future

Comment: Sorry, can't share my email Id :(, you can follow [me on twitter](http://twitter.com/vk_bandi) though :) and i will follow back, you can DM me if you got anything. accept the answer